# Unable to match subsequent regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract the following strings from the main string:

`roundcube_sessauth=-del-; expires=Thu, 06-Aug-2015 03:38:33 GMT; path=/; secure; httponly`,

`roundcube_sessid=dh7a60r14c6qfa3lr7m90; path=/; secure; HttpOnly`,

`roundcube_sessauth=S2124929b7486e6805d615a86; path=/; secure; httponly`

The main string is:

`roundcube_sessauth=-del-; expires=Thu, 06-Aug-2015 03:38:33 GMT; path=/; secure; httponly, roundcube_sessid=dh7a60r14c6qfa3lr7m90; path=/; secure; HttpOnly, roundcube_sessauth=S2124929b7486e6805d615a86; path=/; secure; httponly`

The regex I have is `(roundcube.*?httponly){1}` which matches the first string perfectly. However, it doesn't match the second or third occurrence, i.e `(roundcube.*?httponly){2}` and `(roundcube.*?httponly){3}`

Please let me know what am I doing wrong. I am trying to do this in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly tell the regex engine to match 1 occurrence only with a limiting quantifier `{1}`. Remove it and the regex will work.

Also, I suggest to make it safer with word boundaries:

```
\broundcube.*?\bhttponly\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK5vC6/2) (use ignorecase option!)

In PHP, just [grab the matches](https://ideone.com/gaswfj), not groups.

```
$re = '/\broundcube.*?\bhttponly\b/i'; 
$str = "roundcube_sessauth=-del-; expires=Thu, 06-Aug-2015 03:38:33 GMT; path=/; secure; httponly, roundcube_sessid=dh7a60r14c6qfa3lr7m90; path=/; secure; HttpOnly, roundcube_sessauth=S2124929b7486e6805d615a86; path=/; secure; httponly"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

In case you have newlines in your input, add the `/s` modifier so that `.` could also match newline symbols.

Comment: What about `/roundcube.*?httponly/i`

Comment: @Uchiha: It will work in 99,9% of time, too, IMHO. I just added the word boundaries to make sure we match `roundcube` and not `aroundcube`. BTW, that is why I wrote *Remove it and the regex will work*. I meant the original regex in OP.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks. Perfect! I had forgotten about the group modifier!

Answer (score 1):

```
(roundcube[\s\S]*?httponly)
```

You need to make `.` match `newlines` or use `[\s\S]` instead.Use `i` flag too.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/22

```
$re = "/(roundcube[\\s\\S]*?httponly)/mi"; 
$str = "roundcube_sessauth=-del-; expires=Thu, 06-Aug-2015 03:38:33 GMT; path=/; secure; httponly, roundcube_sessid=dh7a60r14c6qfa3lr7m90; path=/; secure; HttpOnly, roundcube_sessauth=S2124929b7486e6805d615a86; path=/; secure; httponly"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: I doubt you need `/m` option since you do not have `^` or `$` in the pattern. No need using `[\s\S]`, it is PHP and it supports the `/s` modifier. Besides, unless we split a string with a regex, I see no use enclosing the whole expression inside a capturing group.